# Using PIL open a picture but got wrong color

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library

I am new to image processing, when I was using PIL to process the image, I got the wrong color with this picture:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d9/Big_Bear_Valley,_California.jpg

Here is the demo code:

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('/path/to/this/picture')
img.show()
```

[image: Here are the difference between origin photo and PIL]

What's the reason about this problem ? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a handy way of analyzing your jpeg, but there's a possibility that it has an embedded color profile. That profile would be lost when read and rewritten by PIL. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459354/color-profile-detection-in-jpeg

Comment: I found an online EXIF analyzer at http://exif.regex.info/exif.cgi and it confirms that the JPEG has an embedded profile of AdobeRGB. This means you need to use color management to view the file colors properly. PIL has a module [`ImageCMS`](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.4.x/reference/ImageCms.html) but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @MarkRansom thank you! you're right. My problem can be solve with this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041044/convert-jpg-from-adobergb-to-srgb-using-pil

using `alekssaff 's` solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably only what you need to do is to attach image's Color Profile to 'sRGB IEC61966-2.1'. At least that's what helped me. You can do it with a ColorSync macOS app.

I did test on image filled with pure green color and got some weird values like [114 246  74] instead of [0 255 0].

It appears that image had 'Display P3' by default.